# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work as expected since XCode 7 beta 2

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit

I had perfectly working tap handlers before XCode 7 beta 2 which don't work any more. The tap events are not passed to the `UIViewController` handler functions. I'm using tap handlers on UIImageView (with user interaction enabled) and UIView (which is parent of the topmost view). Does anyone have the same problem? Did Apple changed something regarding event propagation or tap gesture?

NOTE: In the first case (`UIImageView`) I have another swipe gesture which is still working, in the second case I have just tap gesture

Comment: Please provide sufficient detail to allow us to attempt to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is perfectly valid (I have upvoted). And here is the answer, to those people who have down voted this question.

This issue is there in production version of XCode 7.0 as well.

Solution:

Within XCode

```
1. Select the UIImageView
2. Switch to Attribute Inspector
3. Select Interaction and 'Check' User Interaction Enabled.
```

If you have connected the gesture, it will work seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the options that you can check.
1. Check if the user interaction is set as YES to the view that the gesture is attached to.
2. Check if the target action method name is exactly same as that is defined in your piece of code.
3. In iOS simulator running on IOS 9 Beta , i had  similar issue. Removing the Tap gesture and then re adding it made it worked. Probably there is some sort of bug for linking issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this happened only in iOS simulator which is running on iOS 9 Beta. The issue cannot be reproduced on real device running iOS 8.2.

I guess since it is a beta version (XCode 7 and iOS 9) there are issues with it.